# javascript not evaluating tab character from input box

Tags: javascript, html, evaluation

I apologize it the title is unclear, but I couldn't think of any other way to really say it; below is a sample of the code I have tried:

```html
<input type="text" id="hor_delim" value="\t" size="2" />
```

```js
var split = String(document.getElementById('hor_delim').value);
var field = List[i].split(split);
```

Where List is an array with each item being a single line from a text area.  The goal of this code is to split the line by the tab character, but for some reason for which I cannot fathom or figure out(through research), it does not evaluate the \t as a tab character, but a literal \t.  I've tried using eval() with no success, so any help here would be appreciated.

---

I managed to solve this after I started thinking about the below(accepted) solution, here is what I came up with.  It's a slight bit of a hack in terms of specificity, but it works;

```js
var split = split.replace("\\t","\t");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `&#09;` HTML entity instead of `\t`:

```
<input type="text" id="hor_delim" value="&#09;" size="2" />​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A8Mnj/

Comment: I'm going to accept this, but this line got me thinking about something else, which lead me to solve the issue in a different way, which I will post below;

Comment: @Daedalus, feel free to post your version as an answer and accept that, if you think it answers the question better. I'm curious to know how you solved it!

Comment: Well, since I can't exactly do that, I've instead edited my question above for the solution I used.

Comment: @Daedalus, your solution makes more sense if you want the users to actually see the string `\t` inside the fields, instead of an actual tab. Now I realize that's probably your intention.